# IE8 not rendering transparent pngs correctly -- never happened before

Tags: internet-explorer, png, transparency

I've never had a problem before with IE 7 or 8 and transparent PNGs until now. I don't know if it's Photoshop or Fireworks that is possibly messed up.

I really don't know what else to say..

here is the link:

It's the three fading images on the home page.

My only guess is that it has to do with the content background being a transparent PNG too.

I've also downloaded pngcrush and I actually can't even get that to run in command line, so any help with that too would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://spirit.vn/en/?p=37 might help

Comment: What are exactly the images that give you a problem? I am not sure I understand to which ones you are referring.

Comment: the success, dedication, and experience text images on the home page. they have a solid black bg color in IE. which isnt supposed to be there

Comment: Yeah. Definitely not working. I think I'm doing everything I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the cycle plugin code, you'll see that the backgrounds become transparent. I haven't looked up why, but it's causing the problem.

Add this to the cycle options and the background will go away =)

```
cleartypeNoBg: true
```

Source:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Answer (score 3):

OK so in your main index file line 14 which says:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/pngfix.js"></script>
```

Replace that with:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/pngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Since that's how you are supposed to use pngfix.js for IE less than IE 7

Try it :) let me know.

Comment: I'm honestly not even going to bother trying that because if you read my post, it clearly says IE 7 and IE 8 are not properly rendering these png images. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

set the style property of the image like this

`<img src="<your-url-img>" style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
         src='<your-url-img>', sizingMethod='scale');" />`

works on ie7 and ie8